# Are there any examples of cross-language redundancy (e.g. "kielbasa sausage")?

Tags: word-choice, loanwords

I am amused by expressions that combine the same word in two different languages, for example:

- Kielbasa sausage: *kielbasa* is Polish for sausage.
- <strike>Chorizo sausage: *chorizo* is Spanish for sausage.</strike>
- Queso cheese: *queso* is Spanish for cheese.
- Carne asada steak: *carne asada* is Spanish for *grilled meat*, therefore you could just say *grilled steak* instead.

This phenomenon is not limited to English. In Spanish you often find not only redundancy but also contradiction:

- *bluyín*: transliteration of blue jeans. A pair of blue jeans is called *un bluyín*.

  - *bluyín azul*: blue *blue jeans* .
  - *bluyín negro*: black *blue jeans* (black jeans).
  - *bluyín blanco*: white *blue jeans* (white jeans).
- *bistec*: transliteration of beef steak.

  - *bistec de res*: beef *beef steak*.
  - *bistec de cerdo*: pork *beef steak* (pork chop).
  - and my favorite, *bistec de pollo*: chicken *beef steak*.

Do you have any other examples that include at least one English word?

Comment: I must say that "chorizo" is not Spanish for "sausage". "Chorizo" is a very specific kind of sausage, and there are other kinds, such as "salchichón", "lomo embuchado", "morcón", etc. So the expression "chorizo sausage" makes perfect sense in English, because "chorizo" qualifies the more generic "sausage".

Comment: @CesarGon: this is a good example of different definitions depending on the region. The definition of *chorizo* in my country of origin (Colombia) is less restrictive. According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chorizo#South_America): *In Argentina, Uruguay and Colombia, chorizo is the name for any coarse meat sausage. Spanish-style chorizo is also available, and is distinguished by the name "chorizo español" ("Spanish chorizo")*. Nevertheless, I think you are right since the interpretation of *chorizo* by English speakers possibly derives from Mexico or Spain.

Comment: +1 Oh, I didn't know that; thanks for explaining. To me, and to most Spaniards in general, "sausage" is in general translated as "salchicha", i.e. the thing you put in your hot dogs, which is barely related to chorizo or other cold meats.

Comment: What is "queso cheese"? I've been unable to find references to it on the web.

Comment: I have seen *queso cheese* used in the context of [queso cheese sauce](http://www.food.com/recipe/queso-cheese-sauce-251994) or [queso cheese dip](http://www.bukisa.com/articles/259955_how-to-make-queso-cheese-dip), meaning a *sauce* or a *dip* made with Mexican (or pseudo-Mexican, e.g. Monterey Jack) cheese.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Such redundancy is rather common in place names, especially when the English usage takes the name from another language and adds its own word for the feature ("river", "hill", "mountain", etc.) See [this list](http://www.fun-with-words.com/redundant_etymology.html) or this long [list of tautological place names](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tautological_place_names), including, e.g.

- Paraguay River ("Great River River")
- River Avon / River Tyne ("River River")
- Dal Lake / Lake Chad / Lake Tahoe ("Lake Lake")
- Bredon Hill ("Hill Hill Hill")
- Summit Peak / Pinnacle Peak (several places with these names)
- Torpenhow Hill (which is fictional, though Torpenhow exists, and while not exactly meaning "Hill Hill Hill", does mean "Head-peak hillock" or "rising-peak hill" or similar)
- Faroe Island ("Sheep island island")
- La Brea Tar Pits ("The Tar Tar Pits")
- Jiayuguan Pass ("Jiayu Pass Pass")
- Milky Way Galaxy ("Milky Way Milky Way" — this is actually a fault with the word "Galaxy"!)
- Timor Leste / East Timor ("East East", but this *is* actually the eastern half of the easternmost island there).

(I've only picked some representative examples; it's a very long list.)

So it would be more interesting to look for examples that *aren't* place names.

Comment: Torpenhow Hill may be a hoax, but it's not fictional. Unlike [Koom Valley](http://wiki.lspace.org/wiki/Koom_Valley).

Comment: @Andrew: I don't understand your comment. No hill named Torpenhow Hill exists, so it's fictional. Are you objecting to the word "fictional" to mean (rather than something related to the literary genre of fiction) ["something invented by the imagination or feigned"](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fiction), ["An imaginative creation or a pretense that does not represent actuality but has been invented", "a lie", "formed or conceived by the imagination", fabricated, fancied, fictitious, "lacking in reality or substance or genuineness"](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/fictional), etc.?

Comment: @ShreevatsaR: Yes I was.

Comment: @Andrew: And do you still think, after looking at the dictionary, that it's a valid objection? [This one was new to me. Maybe it would make a good question for this website…]

Comment: @ShreevatsaR: I guess not. It's not the person using the word who's wrong, it's the English language that's wrong. I'd like words to have a precise meaning.

Comment: Interesting, I never knew galaxy meant *milky way* before! But our galaxy is just called the Galaxy or the Milky Way (or possibly the Milky Way galaxy), not Milky Way Galaxy. Otherwise we could add the Moon Moon and the Sun Sun to the list too :)

Comment: But checking further: `The term "[Milky Way](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Milky_Way)" is a translation of the Latin for "milky road", Via Lactea, in turn derived from the Greek kyklos galaktikos or "milky circle", "milk" also being the root for the Greek word for galaxy, γαλαξίας (galaxias).` So *Milky Way galaxy* -> *milky way milky*.

Answer (score 9):

The most famous example is "The La Brea Tar Pits," which of course means "The The Tar Tar Pits."

Comment: Another jewel from that area is _Los Angeles Angels of Anaheim_: The Angels Angels of Anaheim.

Answer (score 4):

My favorites are when the waiter asks if I want the French dip "with au jus" or asks if I'd be interested in the soup du jour "daily special"!

Answer (score 3):

Since *Torpenhow Hill* has been mostly [debunked](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torpenhow_Hill), my favorite is the Hungarian "bacon szalonna": *szalonna* is Hungarian for *bacon*. (It's used for American-style thin-sliced streaky bacon, as opposed to the traditional mostly-fat *szalonna*.)

Comment: Removed some comments that were not relevant to the answer at all.

Answer (score 1):

> book of the Bible

Does this count?

How about

> déjà vu all over again

Comment: Maybe if we called it "book of the _Biblos_," the Greek word for _book_.

Comment: The Bible is both a book, and made of books, so "book of the Bible" doesn't really count. There actually are books of a book and therefore there's no redundancy.

Comment: And *deja vu all over again* is a deliberate redundancy.

Comment: @Martha, I think by this point in history that phrase is used by people inadvertently as well who are not "in on the joke".

Answer (score 1):

One in Thai: เสื้อเชิ้ต (seua chert) - "shirt shirt".

Comment: What type of shirt is it? Is the *chert* portion derived from English?

Comment: The type is called "plaid shirt" in English. Dress shirts also qualify, but not T-shirts, sweaters and such. Yes, "chert" is from English, as Thai doesn't have the "sh" sound (btw, Thais borrow English words quite easily).

Answer (score 0):

What about "my PIN number"? Does this count?

Comment: That's RAS (Redundant Acronym Syndrome) Syndrome!

Comment: I enter my PIN number into the ATM machine all the time.

Answer (score 0):

‘Koi carp’ (carp carp — 鯉【koi】 is Japanese for carp)

Answer (score 0):

Sahara Desert means--you guessed it, Desert Desert. I think it's common to just call it The Sahara though.