# Examples of "ATM Machine" silly repeats?

Tags: redundancy

Swedes often say *CD Skiva* as in *Compact disk disk*. In English you sometimes say *ATM machine* as in *Automated teller machine machine*. What are other examples of such redundant endings?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Terms for duplicated words](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7037/terms-for-duplicated-words)

Comment: The "what would you call them" part is clearly a dupe. The "what are other examples" part could live on as a community-wiki list.

Comment: Oh, and I fail to see how "compact disk skiva" is in the same league as "compact disk disk".

Comment: I agree it's not exactly in the same league. I was merely offering an anecdote that after translation is similar to make the question more interesting. I'm guessing making this into a community wiki is a moderator power as I seem to be unable to, feel free.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

PIN Number  (Personal Identification Number Number) comes to mind

They are referred to as RAS Syndrome, with the RAS standing for Redundant Acronym Syndrome

Comment: Beat me by a hair!

Answer (score 3):

GUI Interface (Graphical User Interface Interface).

Answer (score 3):

LCD display (Liquid Crystal Display display)

Comment: I've never heard anyone use that.  I've heard LCD screen, though, which is perfectly acceptable.

Answer (score 2):

EULA agreement (End User License Agreement agreement)

Answer (score 2):

This phenomenon isn't exclusive to acronyms either. *The La Brea Tar Pits* can be translated as *The **The Tar** Tar Pits*.

Comment: This is getting into [Torpenhow Hill territory](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6107/examples-of-cross-language-redundancy/6137#6137)…

Answer (score 1):

VIN Number (Vehicle identification number number), also tuna fish.

Comment: Well, tuna is also a fruit. [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tuna).

Comment: The "tuna" in "tuna fish" is an adjective, so the phrase is not truly redundant. "Gimme some fish! What kind of fish? Tuna fish."

Comment: Yakitori chicken would be a possible.

Comment: I was stationed in Japan when I was in the Army. I was a Japanese linguist and it always cracked me up when I would go in the mess hall and they would be serving chicken yakitori. The staff would look at me funny when I would say "I'll take some chicken grilled chicken"

Comment: In Texas - you get Chicken Fried Chicken, as opposed to chicken fried anything else. Chicken fried seems to mean schnitzel

Comment: @RegDwight: would you call those *tuna fruits* (like in *kiwi fruits*)?

Comment: Well, "tuna fish" isn't really in the same category. What if I say, "the Japanease nation"? "The color green"? "British Isles" etc etc Sometimes we are redundant in this sense because the reader may not know what kind of thing something is. Like I might say, "The nation of Tuvalu" because many of my readers might not be aware that there is such a nation, so I need to give them a hint what I'm talking about. And sure, "the British Isles" is redundant in the sense that there is no "British Continent" or "British Moutains", but that's what the place is called.

Answer (score 1):

VAT Tax ( Value Added Tax Tax )

Comment: At least in the UK, I’ve never or rarely heard it called this — it’s generally just *VAT* in my experience.

Comment: i have heard that in india .

Answer (score 0):

AC current/ DC current (alternating current/direct current)

IP protocol (internet protocol)