# Is there a word for "Someone who/Something that caches"?

Tags: word-choice

Cache is defined as:

> noun
>   a collection of items of the same type stored in a hidden or inaccessible place : *an arms cache* | *a cache of gold coins*.

and has the following synonyms:

> hoard, store, stockpile, stock, supply, reserve; arsenal; informal stash.

I'm looking for a word for someone/something that *does* the caching, my first thought was that they are a "Cacher" but that doesn't seem to be a word. This makes sense to me though as you have a "Hoarder", "Storer", "Stockpiler", "Stocker", "supplier" etc.

Does anybody know the right word?

Comment: Hamster? Squirrel?

Comment: Pirate! Yarrr...

Comment: Server-side programmer? IT professional?

Comment: Do you mean "something that caches" to mean, a server that caches data? Or do you mean the place where all the cached data is stored? Guffa's answer would be the latter...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In computer science, the word is *cache*. The same word is used for the collection of items, as the routines responsible for managing them.

Comment: Perfect, you managed to guess that I'm using this in the context of a computer program!

Answer (score 4):

"Cache" is borrowed from French, and should mean a store with an implied meaning of hidden but *easily* accessible to the "right people". Because of that I do not like using "cacher", which is the infinitive of the French verb.

The uncommonly used French word would be a "cacheur".

The word that actually had the meaning, and has become specialised in its own ways, is cashier.

Other words from the same Old French roots are "stash", almost synonymous with cache, and "stasher". I think I prefer "stasher".

Comment: "cashier" actually comes from elsewhere. http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cashier

Answer (score 2):

The [Official Global GPS Cache Hunt Site](http://www.geocaching.com/about/glossary.aspx) seems to think that *cacher* is fine.

Comment: This answer could also be given for this question http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/21382/examples-of-atm-machine-silly-repeats