# Is "Toll fee" correct or not?

Tags: nouns

I saw a tweet on twitter and he was asking if "toll fee" is correct because it is "redundant". I am unsure about the answer because here in the Philippines, we tend to, sometimes, double the noun -- the same with the double negatives Americans do. I then searched whether words like "charge fee" and "tax fee" exist and there was nothing to look up for -- at least not "tax service fee". Is it correct to consider the word "toll fee" or it depends on the Linguistics of our country?

Comment: It seems redundant to me, because a toll is the fee for using a bridge or section of road.

Comment: Sometimes, special usages arise (perhaps in an attempt to disambiguate locally, perhaps through ignorance of standard usages) but these are non-standard unless they gain wider acceptance (and they are thus off-topic on ELU).

Comment: Well, you could have a toll road or a tool booth, so a toll fee emphasizes the amount you pay at the toll. It's like "Cash, only, no checks", which may be repetitious but avoids the next question ("What about a personal check?")

Comment: Just because a term or phrase seems to be redundant does not mean it is "incorrect." The language is full of idiomatic pleonasms like *join together*, *temper tantrum*, or *the weather outside*.

Comment: Is a "death toll" a fee?

Comment: @KateBunting - I'll believe it's redundant when I read the certificate of redundancy certificate from the Department of Redundancy Department.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it can be correct.  It would usually refer to a fee charged *for* a toll generally paid by someone else.

Such fees are common on [rideshares](https://help.lyft.com/hc/en-us/articles/115013081068-How-tolls-work-for-drivers-) ("Toll fees are included in the individual ride breakdown in your ride history"), [rental cars](https://www.tripadvisor.com/ShowTopic-g60713-i30-k6832070-Extra_Toll_Fee_Charges_for_Golden_Gate_Bridge_on_Car_Rentals-San_Francisco_California.html) ("you may be charged an extra fee on top of the $6.00 toll fee"), etc.

Anecdotally, it also appears to see some less common colloquial usage in the redundant sense, similar to ["ATM machine" or "PIN number"](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/21382/390415).

Answer (score 0):

It is not an American English idiom. If you are asking could it be an idiom, then sure it could be in another culture. Often doubled or act as intensifiers or as sarcastic commentary, so **toll fee** might fit right in there.