# A term for redundancy in loan words?

Tags: loanwords, foreign-phrases

Unfortunately, I can only think of one example at the moment, but, sometimes a loan or borrowed phrase is redundant because it includes in it both the lending and borrowing languages' words for the same meaning.

The example: There is a famous street in Seoul named *가로수길*, romanized as *Garosugil*. The *Garosu* part means *lined with trees* and *gil* means *street*. Yet, it is sometimes referred to in English as *Garosugil **Street***--that's Garosu Street Street. It appears to be done to keep both the recognizable name as well as explain what it is more generally.

I'm sure there are other examples, and would appreciate some just for the sake of interest. I am, however, also searching for a term to describe this construction, if one exists.

Comment: This type of redundancy doesn't only occur in loan words, it also happens with acronums. Consider _PIN number_, where the N already stands for Number.

Comment: “The hoi polloi” is another well known example.

Comment: I think the most well known example is River Avon ("afon" is "river" in Welsh). Torpenhow Hill is discussed as meaning hill hill hill hill, but, as [this article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torpenhow_Hill) points out, there are a couple of flaws with that, such as the place not existing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be termed *[cross-language redundancy](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6107/are-there-any-examples-of-cross-language-redundancy-e-g-kielbasa-sausage/6137#6137)* (according to a post at StackExchange).

There's a Russian word прейскурант (prejskurant), a loan from either German or Dutch, where it means/meant "a price list" (prejs + curant); google finds a lot of instances of Prijscourant. In Russian, a redundant combination *прейскурант цен* (prejskurant tsen) has sprung up, meaning literally "a preijskurant of prices" (цен = of prices), that is, "a price list of prices".