# A word for "using two words next to each other that mean the same thing"?

Tags: single-word-requests, linguistics

I'm not even sure if there is a word for this. My partner says there is but I can't find it anywhere.

The example I'm giving is **garlic aioli**. The word *aioli* is a Mediterranean garlic and olive oil sauce, so why do they put garlic in front of the word *aioli*? It's like saying garlic, garlic and olive oil sauce.

Another example is **Loch Ness lake**, because apparently *loch* means lake in Scottish, it's like saying lake-Ness lake.

Anyways, I dunno if that makes much sense at all. Is there a word for that?

Comment: I believe it's called a **tautological pleonasm**... {removes tongue from cheek}.

Comment: Related (possible dupe): [cross-language redundancy](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/6107/8019).

Comment: I'm not sure how it is in other English speaking countries, but here in the States, the meaning of aioli has drifted rather away from the original rather quickly, at least as far as the culinarily unsophisticated are concerned.  It is frequently used to simply mean high-end flavored mayonnaise.  With this usage, garlic aioli is not redundant.

Comment: I would think that siamonyms would be the term.

Comment: "perfectly sensible noun adjunct."

Comment: Relevant: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torpenhow_Hill

Comment: @AndyT Sounds sexual.

Comment: These expressions ought to be filed with the department of redundancy dept.

Comment: South of Oslo, Norway, there is a municipality called "Nesoddtangen", which basically means "the pensinsula-peninsula peninsula" (nes, odde, tange) (I'm not completely certain of my topographical terms in English, so "peninsula" might not be the best translation). If something were to happen there, and it would make international news, I am willing to bet money that English language news sites would report it as "The Nesoddtangen peninsula".

Comment: Related: [RAS syndrome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAS_syndrome).

Answer (score 39):

The word you want is **[pleonasm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pleonasm):**

> Pleonasm (/ˈpliːənæzəm/; from Greek πλεονασμός (pleonasmós), from πλέον (pleon), meaning "more, too much") is the use of more words or parts of words than are necessary or sufficient for clear expression: examples are black darkness, burning fire. Such redundancy is, by traditional rhetorical criteria, a manifestation of tautology. That being said, people may use a pleonasm for emphasis or because the phrase has already become established in a certain form.

A context-relevant excerpt from the article body:

> Redundancies sometimes take the form of foreign words whose meaning is repeated in the context:
>
> - "We went to **the El Restaurante restaurant.**"
> - "**The La Brea tar** pits are fascinating."
> - "Roast beef served **with au jus sauce**."
> - "**Please** R.**S.V.P**."
> - "The Schwarz**wald Forest** is deep and dark."
> - "The Drakens**berg Mountains** are in South Africa."

At chux's request, here are some examples without foreign phrases, courtesy of *[Mental Floss](http://mentalfloss.com/article/30687/say-pleonasm-9-common-phrases-longer-they-need-be)*:

- Nape of the neck
- Gnashing of teeth
- False pretense
- Safe haven
- Bleary-eyed
- Veer off course

---

If the term is too technical for you, you could simply say that saying Loch Ness lake is **[redundant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redundancy_(linguistics))**.

(Source: Wikipedia)

Comment: Fine. I'll bite. PIN Number **is** a pleonasm: a redundant acronym. See the linked Wikipedia page. Also, It **is** possible for a word/phrase to be tautologous while being a pleonasm. The two aren't mutually exclusive.

Comment: From the 'redundant' link in your post - ***Redundancy** typically takes the form of tautology... **A more general classification** of redundancy is pleonasm*.  Tautology is narrowly defined and most precisely answers the OP.  Pleonasm, even though it is often used to mean tautology actually has a broader, more catch-all meaning.

Comment: @Dan: (A)Your previous comment is an indictment of `redundancy`; not `ploeonasm` (B) Your ellipsis is misleading; the 'more general classification' is very likely a reference to 'RAS' syndrome in the previous para, not to 'redundancy' two paras above, which arguably isn't a classification at all (C) Seeing as tautology has all sorts of other meanings inside and outside the field of language, I'd say pleonasm is the narrow one here. However, everyone is free to choose whatever term they prefer. They're both right.

Comment: I'm a fan of "ATM Machine", myself.

Comment: @Ghotir: Ah. The old RAS syndrome!

Comment: Considering this in an English site, examples that do not rely on a 2nd language would be more interesting.

Comment: @chux See edit. Went with the foreign ones earlier as those were what the OP mentioned.

Comment: And nobody mentioned "the Los Angeles Angels"?

Comment: @Ghotir LED diode, for that sake.

Comment: @yo' Or LED light, to get tricky.

Comment: In a similar vein, “tad bit” is one of my pet peeves.

Comment: I don't know about other countries but in the UK people often refer to the Vehicle Identification Number of a car as its VIN _Number_. And VINs are older that PINs.

Comment: In Australia, we have koalas and platypuses. In America, people often call them koala **bears** and **duck-billed** platypuses respectively, which is inaccurate in both cases. Koalas are marsupials, so are not related to bears (which are placentals) apart from both being mammals. Platypuses are monotremes which are also mammals, so they can't have an avian beak. There is also only one species of animal called "platypus" so there's no need to try to distinguish them further.

Comment: *Free gift* still persists.

Comment: My personal favorite/pet peeve: "Chai tea."

Comment: @Jeutnarg: I wonder at what point we stop considering the use of a pleonasm as a mistake, in the case where avoiding the pleonasm _introduces ambiguity_. If the addition of the so-called pleonasm reduces ambiguity, then it isn't an irrelevant addition, and imo not a pleonasm. "The Los Angeles Angels" (the team) differentiates itself from "Los Angeles" (the city).

Comment: Some terms use this to ensure that all people understood the result.  For example "without let or hindrance", where "let" means "hindrance" just as it still does in tennis.

Answer (score 22):

***Tautology*** - Unnecessary repetition, usually in close proximity, of ***the same*** word, phrase, idea, argument, etc. The saying of the same thing twice in different words generally considered to be a fault of style (OED) although it can be used as a [literary device](https://literarydevices.net/tautology/).

Consider PIN...

> "*PIN number*" is *tautologous* - it repeats "number" next to the initial N, which means "number".
>
> "*My PIN number that I use to identify my card with is on this piece of paper" - **that I use to identify my card with*** is also tautologous.

When 'the same thing' is repeated in different languages (eg the examples in the OP) - *Loch* Ness *Lake*, La *Brea* *Tar* Pits, Drankens*berg* *Mountains*, Schwarz*wald* *Forest* - or, involves unfamiliar jargon - DV*D* *disk*, ISB*N* *number* - the tautology may not be *redundant* (superfluous, excessive; surplus; unnecessary (OED)), but in fact necessary for clarity (until such time as speaker and spoken-to can understand the unfamiliar language).

Tautology is a kind of *pleonasm* which is when more words are used in a sentence or clause than are necessary for clear expression (either as a fault of style, or as a rhetorical figure used for emphasis or clarity). For example,

> *Jill saw the building burning down with her own eyes*. (She must have seen it with her own eyes).
>
> *The vote was completely and totally unanimous*. (A unanimous vote cannot be anything but complete and total).

Although *tautology* and *pleonasm* are closely related, they are not synonyms. A tautology is a kind of pleonasm by definition.  The reverse is not the case.

(Note that this answer refers to ***tautology*** in its original, *rhetorical* sense.  In the early twentieth century philosophers Bertrand Russell and Ludwig Wittgenstein used the term tautology to describe a formula of the propositional calculus which is true under every assignment of truth or falsehood to its propositional letters, for example ‘If p and q then p’. In this context it is also used more widely to describe any proposition which is true because of its logical form rather than its content (OED)).

Comment: Similar to the warning given by @TusharRaj my familiarity with this word relates to [mathematical logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tautology_(logic)). In that context it has a related but different meaning that generally lacks negative connotation. I expect many people from a mathematical or software background would only be familiar with the definition from logic.  The term "rhetorical tautology" from the wikipedia article eliminates ambiguity.

Comment: @Dan Here is a footnote from R. Dawkins's The Ancestor's Tale "Gonwanaland is a tautology, because vana in Sanskrit means land (actually forest.) I shall not use it." ...(From The Elephant Bird's Tale)

Comment: PIN number has been asked before: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/14868/pin-number-why-do-we-say-it

Comment: Thankyou all very much! And I'm getting a good laugh out of the other examples too 